# knockout js, add additional elements to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I have an app where I want to add extra elements to an item in an array, I have [created a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martin461/wzrnj8eo/) of what I'm trying to achieve.

So the user starts the app, they click next fill in some details of an item and a description, they then should click next and fill in a price for the item(this is where I'm stuck). This example works up to a point, as in whenever I try and implement the price part I seem to be getting it wrong. You'll see once I click next the item is added to the array, however how do add more elements to the current item in the array. In case I've not made sense the logic should be:

Start
Page one (enter name and description)
Page two (enter price)

I understand I could do this all on one page but I don't want to I want knockout to be able to add a price after the name and description page. I would also like to be able to go back and amend the item. Can you anybody help in seeing what I should be doing next?

When I insert the name and description, do I have to also make an empty element in the array for the price? Then once the price is entered somehow insert this into the price element in the array? Not sure how/if this should be implemented.

This is my first knockout app so I be surprised if what I've actually done is correct, any help or pointers gratefully received :)

My code is below:

```js
$(function() {
 var main = new stuff();
 ko.applyBindings(main, $('#ko')[0]);
});

function Item(data) {
 this.itemname = ko.observable(data.itemname);
 this.itemdescription = ko.observable(data.itemdescription);
 this.itemenabled = ko.observable(data.itemenabled);
}

function stuff() {
 var self = this;

 self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.newItemName = ko.observable();
 self.newItemDescription = ko.observable();
 self.newItemEnabled = ko.observable();

 // Operations
 self.addItem = function() {
  self.items.push(new Item({
   itemname: this.newItemName(),
   itemdescription: this.newItemDescription(),
   itemenabled: this.newItemEnabled()
  }));
 };
};

//jquery stuff
$('#start').on('click', function(e) {
 $("#page1").show(500);
 $('#panel1').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
 $("#start").hide(500);
})

$('#back').on('click', function(e) {
 $("#panel1").hide(500);    
 $("#page1").hide(500);    
 $("#start").show(500);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start</button>

<div id="ko">
 <div class="panel panel-default hidden" id="panel1">
  <div id="page1">
   <form data-bind="submit: addItem">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;" id="panel2">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="form-group row">
       <label for="inputItemName" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">Enter Item Name</label>
       <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inputItemName" data-bind="value: newItemName" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
       <label for="textareaItemDescription" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">Enter Item Description</label>
       <div class="col-lg-8">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="textareaItemDescription" rows="3" data-bind="value: newItemDescription"></textarea>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-inline no_indent" style="font-weight:bold;">
         <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked="checked" data-bind="checked: newItemEnabled">
         <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
         <span class="custom-control-description" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">Enabled</span>
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="back">Back</button>
    <div class="pull-right">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next1">Next</button>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

 <ul data-bind="foreach: items, visible: items().length > 0">
  <li>
   <input data-bind="value: itemname" style="color: black;" />
  </li>
  <li>
   <input data-bind="value: itemdescription" style="color: black;" />
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: itemenabled" />
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I notice you are using jquery for the click event. You should use KO bindings. They are better because it is clear then from the HTML what is going on

Comment: What do you mean by "how do add more elements to the current item in the array." It is not clear what your issue is

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to edit the current values?

Comment: Also some of you variable names are camel cased and some are not. Try to be consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have added a new observable to track the page number along with basic functions to increment/decrement the number then I simply add the new item after the price has also been added.

```js
$(function() {
  var main = new stuff();
  ko.applyBindings(main, $('#ko')[0]);
});

function Item(data) {
  this.itemname = ko.observable(data.itemname);
  this.itemdescription = ko.observable(data.itemdescription);
  this.itemenabled = ko.observable(data.itemenabled);
  this.price = ko.observable(data.itemprice);
}

function stuff() {
  var self = this;

  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.newItemName = ko.observable();
  self.newItemDescription = ko.observable();
  self.newItemEnabled = ko.observable();
  self.newItemPrice = ko.observable();
  self.page = ko.observable(1);
  // Operations
  self.next = function() {
    if (self.page() === 2) {
      self.addItem();
    }
    self.page(self.page() + 1)
  }

  self.back = function() {
    if (self.page() == 1) {
      $("#panel1").hide(500);
      $("#page1").hide(500);
      $("#start").show(500);
    }
    self.page(self.page() - 1);
  }

  self.addItem = function() {
    self.items.push(new Item({
      itemname: this.newItemName(),
      itemdescription: this.newItemDescription(),
      itemenabled: this.newItemEnabled(),
      itemprice: this.newItemPrice(),
    }));
  };
};

//jquery stuff
$('#start').on('click', function(e) {
  $("#page1").show(500);
  $('#panel1').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
  $("#start").hide(500);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start</button>

<div id="ko">
  <div class="panel panel-default hidden" id="panel1">
    <div id="page1">
      <form data-bind="submit: next">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;" id="panel2">
          <div class="container" data-bind="if: page() == 1">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputItemName" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">Enter Item Name</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inputItemName" data-bind="value: newItemName" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="textareaItemDescription" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">Enter Item Description</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="textareaItemDescription" rows="3" data-bind="value: newItemDescription"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-inline no_indent" style="font-weight:bold;">
         <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" checked="checked" data-bind="checked: newItemEnabled">
         <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
         <span class="custom-control-description" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">Enabled</span>
        </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" data-bind="if: page() == 2">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputPrice" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">Enter Price</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inputPrice" data-bind="value: newItemPrice" placeholder="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: back" class="btn btn-primary" id="back">Back</button>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="next1">Next</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul data-bind="foreach: items, visible: items().length > 0">
    <li>
      <input data-bind="value: itemname" style="color: black;" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input data-bind="value: itemdescription" style="color: black;" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="price">Price</label>
      <input id="price" data-bind="value: price" style="color: black;" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: itemenabled" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is pretty much what I'm after, however say the user gets to the end of the creating an item process then decides they want to go back and change the item name how would they do that? If they click the previous button its not loading the item that's in the array?

Comment: You can create the new item at the first stage and intilialse the price with 0

Comment: Hi there, me again, seem to be going round in circles with this. However lets say before I even use the 'creating an item' app I want to add some items into my array that I have from a database, how would I do this? I have collected the items from the db fine its just I cannot just seem to go .addtem and have this added to my array ifswim

Comment: I don't see why there would be any issue doing that. Create a new question and I will have a look for you