# knockout js, add new item to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, knockout.js

So this follows on from my previous question:

[knockout js, add additional elements to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825629/knockout-js-add-additional-elements-to-an-array)

Basically I have an app where a user fills in certain data, clicks next and this is added to an array. However, what I'd like to do is add some items into the array before the user even begins using the app (these items I get from a database). The idea being that at the start they can view each item in the array and then choose and an item and edit this item. I've got a feeling I'm missing something blindingly obvious but I cannot seem to figure it out

Comment: Have you looked at the knockout tutorials? I'd suggest taking the answer to your previous question as a starting point, replacing the items array with this: `self.items = ko.observableArray([ new Item({}), new Item({}) ])` and see what happens.

Comment: yes, though I'm still very much a beginner, I don't get how I can pass the item into the {} part

Comment: With the information you're providing, the only question that we can answer is "How do you put initial items in an observable array". If there are more complicated problems you're trying to tackle, you'll have to put some extra effort in explaining the details and you'll need to show us what you've tried.

Comment: I do have a fiddle (which I've currently broken), hang fire shall get it into a state I show

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/martin461/wzrnj8eo/

Comment: where I have put 'Insert initial items here' this would be where I would want items added at the start and have them displayed

Answer (score 0):

Knockout observable arrays have equivalent functions to native JavaScript arrays. See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

So you need just to use arr.pop(item) or arr.push(item).

In case you need to replace all items and want to avoid multiple events to raise, use observableArray.valueWillMutate() and valueHasMutated() functions. See sample where I do swap the entire array:

```js
ko.observableArray.fn.replaceWith = function (valuesToPush) {
  // NOTE: base on - ko.observableArray.fn.pushAll
  var underlyingArray = this();
  var oldItemcount = underlyingArray.length;

  this.valueWillMutate();

  // adding new items to obs. array
  ko.utils.arrayPushAll(underlyingArray, valuesToPush);

  // removing old items (using KO observablearray fnc.)
  if (oldItemcount > 0)
   this.removeAll(underlyingArray.slice(0, oldItemcount));

  this.valueHasMutated();

  return this;  //optional
 };
```