# KnockoutJS and binding data from JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js, data-binding

I have a problem to get data from returning JSON in case of nested JSON objects.

HTML code looks like:

```
<table>   
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: resource.name[0].text"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: dob"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: gender"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: fullUrl"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

then KnockoutJS

```
   function PatientsViewModel() {
      var self = this;

      self.rows= ko.observableArray([]);
      self.resources = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.name = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.text = ko.observable("");
      self.dob = ko.observable("");
      self.gender = ko.observable("");
      self.address = ko.observable("");
      self.fullUrl = ko.observable("");

        $.getJSON(
            "/proxy.php",
            {
                last: "john",
                first: "smith",
                dob: 19700101

            },
            function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data.entry));
                self.rows(data.entry);
            }
        );

    }

    ko.applyBindings(new PatientsViewModel());
```

and JSON response structure looks like:

```
[
   {
      "fullUrl":"https://www.example.com/Patient/123",
      "resource":{
         "resourceType":"Patient",
         "id":"123",
         "identifier":[
            {
               "use":"official",
               "type":{
                  "coding":[
                     {
                        "system":"http://hl7.org/fhir/v2/0203",
                        "code":"MR",
                        "display":"test data"
                     }
                  ],
                  "text":"test"
               },
               "system":"1.2.3.4.5",
               "value":"123",
               "assigner":{
                  "display":"PatientId"
               }
            }
         ],
         "active":true,
         "name":[
            {
               "use":"usual",
               "text":"John Smith",
               "family":[
                  "Smith"
               ],
               "given":[
                  "John"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "gender":"Male",
         "birthDate":"1970-01-01",
         "address":[
            {
               "use":"home",
               "type":"both",
               "line":[
                  ""
               ],
               "city":"",
               "state":"",
               "postalCode":"",
               "country":""
            }
         ]
      },
      "search":{
         "mode":"match",
         "score":0
      }
   }
]
```

and when I try to bind data from JSON response work fine only for `fullUrl` can't get anything like `resource.name[0].text`, `resource.birthDate` etc

Any tips what I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Just add some breakpoints, I'm sure you do KO binding before getting data with getJSON (see: [getJSON does not honor async:false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282821/getjson-does-not-honor-asyncfalse)).

Another issue might be that the data you get is JSON, and aren't observables, but you can help on that easily: var koViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(uiModel); But you'll need this JS lib too: knockout.mapping.js

Comment: Should `rows` in my case be observable or just to declare as `rows : data.entry`?

Comment: it depends, if you need to track and do two way binding on their content or the count, or if you plan to add items to that array manually, then i'd have them as an observable. anyhow the knockout.mapping.js will do the job for you :D

for array manipulation check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920118/knockout-js-add-new-item-to-an-array/43922961#43922961